# Proof of Peter Weyl's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Qualcuno potrebbe spiegarmi i passaggi della dimostrazione della prima parte del teorema di Peter weyl dove si afferma: lo spazio generato dalla combinazione lineare di coefficienti matriciali di rappresentazioni unitarie irriducibili di un gruppo compatto è denso in L2

In English:

Could someone explain to me the steps of the proof of the first part of Peter weyl's theorem in A.Knapp "beyond an introduction" where it is stated: the space generated by the linear combination of matrix coefficients of irreducible unitary representations of a compact group is dense in L2.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Please, write in English, so all of us can understand your question.

Comment: It would be good if you could post the first part of the proof so we can see it. As it stands, you are asking us to find this proof and then figure out how much of it constitutes the first part and what part you don't understand.

Comment: I'm trying. So in A. knapp the author create a succession of function and then F(x) =f2(x)+f2(x) coniug  and i dont understan why

Comment: I know you are being bombarded with formatting requests, but... Relying on images is also frowned upon, for accessibility reasons. [See here for an explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The reason why seems obvious enough. He needs a continuous $F$ in $U^\perp$, with the properties that $F(gxg^{-1}) = F(x)$ for all $g$, $F(1)$ is real and non-zero, and $F(x) = \overline {F(x^{-1})}$. Why he needs these properties will presumably become apparent later in the proof, But that is not reproduced here.

Comment: How can i write the elements that are in Uortogonal  where Uortogonal Is the linear span of all Matrix coefficients for all finite dimentional irriducible unitary representations?